# Eliminar tag de HTML en una respuesta de un objeto JSON

Tags: javascript, reactjs, regex, react-native

¡Buenos días! El objeto me devuelve la cadena que muestro abajo y me gustaría eliminar todos los tag de HTML, así como #html-body [data....] {just...}

```
<style>#html-body [data-pb-style=XV6R274]{justify-content:flex-start;display:flex;flex-direction:column;background-position:left top;background-size:cover;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:scroll;border-style:none;border-width:1px;border-radius:0;margin:0 0 10px;padding:10px}#html-body [data-pb-style=YJCQDA4]{border-style:none;border-width:1px;border-radius:0;margin:0;padding:0}</style><div data-content-type="row" data-appearance="contained" data-element="main"><div data-enable-parallax="0" data-parallax-speed="0.5" data-background-images="{}" data-background-type="image" data-video-loop="true" data-video-play-only-visible="true" data-video-lazy-load="true" data-video-fallback-src="" data-element="inner" data-pb-style="XV6R274"><div data-content-type="html" data-appearance="default" data-element="main" data-pb-style="YJCQDA4">Las adidas Ultra Boost son unas zapatillas de running de alto rendimiento lanzadas al mercado en 2015. Gracias al tejido Primeknit y la tecnología BOOST™, ofrecen un ajuste ligero y flexible, así como una gran amortiguación y un excelente retorno de energía en cada zancada.</div></div></div>
```

Actualmente lo tengo montado así.

```
const result = data.category.description
const regex = /(<([^>]+)>)/ig;
setResultSubtitle(result ? result.replace(regex, "") : '');
```

Pero regex no me consigue eliminar los claves #html-body [data....] {just...}
Debería de quedar así

> Las adidas Ultra Boost son unas zapatillas de running de alto rendimiento lanzadas al mercado en 2015. Gracias al tejido Primeknit y la tecnología BOOST™, ofrecen un ajuste ligero y flexible, así como una gran amortiguación y un excelente retorno de energía en cada zancada.

¿Alguien qué pueda ayudarme?

Comment: ¡Esta pregunta es un clásico! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Todos hemos pasado alguna vez por algo así :-)

Comment: Por cierto, bienvenido a SOes, puedes completar el [tour] para ganarte tu primera medalla y conocer un poco mejor el sitio y su temática, aunque tu primera pregunta está bien planteada y expresada.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final lo he resuelto así

```
const regexHtml = /<(?:..|\n)*?>/gm;
setResultSubtitle(result ? result.replace(regexHtml, "") : "");
```

Answer (score 3):

No puedes usar expresiones regulares para parsear HTML porque HTML no es un [lenguage regular](https://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lenguaje_regular).

Puedes parsear el HTML y obtener el elemento que quieres creando un documento y usando los métodos clásicos para navegar por el DOM:

```js
const texto ='<style>#html-body [data-pb-style=XV6R274]{justify-content:flex-start;display:flex;flex-direction:column;background-position:left top;background-size:cover;background-repeat:no-repeat;background-attachment:scroll;border-style:none;border-width:1px;border-radius:0;margin:0 0 10px;padding:10px}#html-body [data-pb-style=YJCQDA4]{border-style:none;border-width:1px;border-radius:0;margin:0;padding:0}</style><div data-content-type="row" data-appearance="contained" data-element="main"><div data-enable-parallax="0" data-parallax-speed="0.5" data-background-images="{}" data-background-type="image" data-video-loop="true" data-video-play-only-visible="true" data-video-lazy-load="true" data-video-fallback-src="" data-element="inner" data-pb-style="XV6R274"><div data-content-type="html" data-appearance="default" data-element="main" data-pb-style="YJCQDA4">Las adidas Ultra Boost son unas zapatillas de running de alto rendimiento lanzadas al mercado en 2015. Gracias al tejido Primeknit y la tecnología BOOST™, ofrecen un ajuste ligero y flexible, así como una gran amortiguación y un excelente retorno de energía en cada zancada.</div></div></div>';

const parser = new DOMParser();

const documento = parser.parseFromString(texto,'text/html');
//documento es un HTMLDocument, con lo que podemos usar el API del DOM:
console.log(documento.querySelector('div[data-content-type=html]').innerHTML)
```

Comment: En React Native, no puedo usar el DOMParser ¿Cómo podría hacerlo?

Comment: Siempre hay una librería para resolver cualquier problema: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-dom-parser, o https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-html-parser

Comment: No me sirve ninguna, con ambas parece meterle más código

Comment: ¿Qué quieres decir? La segunda opción parece sencilla: `var DomParser = require('react-native-html-parser').DOMParser; let doc = new DomParser().parseFromString(html,'text/html');`

Comment: Es sencilla de implementar, el problema es no me saca el string solamente.

Comment: Gracias @Pablo Lozano :-)